# Retrain a saved model in Keras that was trained using train_on_batch()

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I am working on GANS and I need to save the model after my working hours. And then I have to retrain that previously saved model again where it was saved. I am saving these three models to continue training later on.

```
Discriminator Model.h5
Generator Model.h5
Generator-on-Discriminator Model.h5
```

For these models, I am using `perceptual loss` and `Wasserstein loss`. But when I `load_model` to retrain that saved model again it encounters the following error.

```
Unknown loss function:wasserstein_loss
```

I have also tried `Discriminator.compile(loss=Wasserstein loss)` but this still not solving my issue. Can anyone of you please guide me over this and can tell me wither its possible to retrain a saved model using train_on_batch().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**solved at my own**

Defining `custom_objects={'wassertein_loss':wassertein_loss}` along with path while loading the model solved my issue. i.e.

```
Discriminator=load_model(model_path, custom_objects={'wassertein_loss':wassertein_loss} )
```